# Memory unclaimed for statics

Tags: java

This is a suspicion I have had in mind and thought to thrash it out for good.
Suppose I have the following class which is loaded as part of my application:

```
class HeavyClass {
    static final ArrayList list = new ArrayList(100);
}
```

Does the lifecycle of the static member align itself to the application,irrespective of what happens to instance of HeavyClass.
If the static aligns itself to the classloader memory(permgen) which is not garbage collected  - what is the programming idiom to make sure such an object only consumes(and cleans up members) on a need basis ;assuming we have to have a static to be shared across all instances)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the lifecycle of the static member align itself to the application,irrespective of what happens to instance of HeavyClass.

Pretty much, yes.  See BevnQ's answer.

> If the static aligns itself to the classloader memory(permgen) which is not garbage collected ...

While the static frame for a class is (typically) allocated in permgen:

1. permgen memory >>is<< garbage collected, and
2. the objects references from the static frame (e.g. the arraylist) are not allocated in permgen.

However, neither of these facts actually change anything ... unless your application does successfully dispose of the classloader that loaded the class in question.

> what is the programming idiom to make sure such an object only consumes(and cleans up members) on a need basis ;assuming we have to have a static to be shared across all instances)

The problem is knowing when the members are no longer needed.  If the members can be regenerated, you can implement a cache using weak references.  This is a common solution and works reasonably well, though you may want to put a bound on the cache size.  (An unbounded cache can consume a lot of memory that is better used for other things.  You won't get OOME's but you will end up running the GC more frequently.)

Otherwise, you will need to implement some kind of reference counting mechanism, and hope that all "clients" of the shared data structure obey the rules ... all of the time.  That's not a good solution.

My recommendation would be to figure out how to avoid using a static or (more generally) a large shared data structure that is permanently "root reachable".

Answer (score 6):

Static variables exist for the life of the class object. That is they are created when the class is loaded and usually only die when the ClassLoader is disposed of.

If the list is to be attached to an instance of `HeavyClass` you should not make it `static`,
Calling `list.clear()` in the `finalize` method will give you `unpredictable results`.

Refer to [java language spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.1)

8.3.1.1. static Fields

If a field is declared static, there exists exactly one incarnation of the field, no matter how many instances (possibly zero) of the class may eventually be created. A static field, sometimes called a class variable, is incarnated when the class is initialized (§12.4).